# Jquery Date calculation not working on clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, date

Currently working on calculating the expeerience using jquery date picker  from date and to date. For example (**if user select the date 01/05/2010 (from) - (To) 31 / 07 / 2013 --  result will be 3years and 3 months**) the result will be shown in label format. Again when the user click add more button one more row will be generated here also the user enter the from date and to date. The resule will be both the two rows (**if user select the date 01/05/2010 (from) - (To) 31 / 07 / 2013 --  result will be 6years and 6 months**) it has to calulate both rows.

Here is the Jquery code which wrote for the current calculation

```
   $(document).on('change', "#txt_Tdob", function (){
    var date1 = document.getElementById("txt_Fdob").value;
    var date2 = document.getElementById("txt_Tdob").value;
    var x = date1.split("-");
    var y = date2.split("-");
    var fromdate = new Date(x[2], x[0] - 1, x[1]);
    var todate = new Date(y[2], y[0] - 1, y[1]);
    var diffDays = parseInt((todate - fromdate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var year = parseInt(diffDays / 365);
    var date = diffDays - (365 * year);
    var month = parseInt(date / 30);
    document.getElementById("txt_expy").innerHTML = year + " year";
    document.getElementById("txt_expm").innerHTML = month + " Month";
});
```

Here is the fiddle [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/ezm4hty2/2/)

Note : As per this fiddle link the first time when the user click the datepicker it won't work only if the user click add more button from the second time only this will work

Kindly help me

Thanks & Regards
Mahadevan

Comment: you are attaching event to `id`. Try attaching it to `class` instead.

Comment: can you please update the fiddle

Comment: Can you please update the fiddle so that `jquery-ui` datepicker works. Its not working right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is the updated code for you and kindly note that **validations for future date** has not been done. I mean if you select future year it will just add it to total experience and you need to refine your code into much better one as it might still contain cloned `id`s. I have just shown here how you can achieve the functionality.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ezm4hty2/3/)**

```
$(document).on('change', ".datepicker", function (){
    //.datepicker is a common class for all datepickers and change in any datepicker will trigger this
    var valid=true;//check if all the datepickers have been selected
    $.each($('.datepicker'),function(){
        if($(this).val()=="")//if any of datepickers value is null do not add
        {
            valid=false;//set valid to false and return
            return false;
        }
     });
     if(valid)//only if it is valid perform adding operation
     {
        var dateStart=[];//create an array to store startDate
        var dateEnd=[];//and endDate
        $.each($('.datepicker'),function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('startDate')) //if the current control is startdate push it to corresponding array
                dateStart.push($(this).val())
            else
                dateEnd.push($(this).val())
        });
        $.each($(dateStart),function(key,value){
            var x = dateStart[key].split("-"); //get first startdate from array
            var y = dateEnd[key].split("-"); //get first enddate from array
            var fromdate = new Date(x[2], x[0] - 1, x[1]);
            var todate = new Date(y[2], y[0] - 1, y[1]);
            diffDays+= parseInt((todate - fromdate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            //diffDays is now a global variable which is declared in document.ready. 
            //You can find it in fiddle
        });
        var year = parseInt(diffDays / 365);
        var date = diffDays - (365 * year);
        var month = parseInt(date / 30);    
        document.getElementById("txt_expy").innerHTML = year + " year";
        document.getElementById("txt_expm").innerHTML = month + " Month";
        //rest all things down here remains same.
     }
});
```

**HTML has been updated little bit. Kindly check in fiddle**

Answer (score 0):

Yes i am already doing that, sure i will provide you with the code..

I have two Date fields: Date From & Date To:

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[id*=DateFrom]').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' }, { changeMonth: true }, { changeYear: true });
$('input[id*=DateTo]').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' }, { changeMonth: true }, { changeYear: true });
});
//Re-create ID for neccessary controls //Here i am changing the id's of cloned elements
tbodyElement.find("#DateFrom" + LstCount).attr('id', 'DateFrom' + varCount);
tbodyElement.find("#DateTo" + LstCount).attr('id', 'DateTo' + varCount);
//input field
<%= Html.TextBox("DateFrom", item.DateFrom.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), new { @id = "DateFrom" + cnt  })%>
//Date To
<%= Html.TextBox("DateTo", item.DateTo.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), new { @id = "DateTo" + cnt })%>
```